# How to react to a conversation where a friend is indirectly revealed as trans/fluid

Tags: gender, lgbt+

I was in a conversation with a friend who revealed they identified as "trans/fluid". It wasn't said as a declaration, rather it was said in such a way as if I already knew about it. I hid my surprise moderately well and rolled with the conversation as if I did already know.

I did this because I was embarrassed - not because of what they said, I don't care about that, just because of I thought this was probably important to them and the way they said it made me think I might have been told before and forgotten, but having time to reflect, I don't think that's the case.

What I want to know is twofold:

How I should have reacted/How should I react in a similar situation in future

If I should do anything now to explain that I didn't know (And do I also say clearly that it doesn't matter to me, or is that dismissive?) or do I just continue on like I knew already (which is now true for future conversations!)

Appreciate that every individual is different, but I would especially appreciate input from other trans/fluid individuals.

Comment: like in most situations, people tend to forget things, even important dates. How many times do movies and TV shows make fun of absent-minded males on forgetting anniversaries and what not? fairly frequently. So forgetting something a friend told you isn't exactly unusual. Especially if it's something not as important to you as it is to them.

Comment: Hey there!  Your question is closed because asking us "what to do" is too broad, and leads to opinion based answers.  If you update your question to target a specific goal, we may be able to help you find answers to your question.

Comment: I could/would answer this one, but as the question is phrased it is indeed a what to do question. Perhaps if you could phrase it as a question 'What is an appropriate response to a friend's indirect revelation as trans/fluid?' and edit the body such that you leave in your original response, but leave out the questions regarding future conversations with said friend (If I should do ...), because those specifically make this is a 'what to do' type question.

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing is to keep in mind that your friend is like any individual you'll ever meet; just a normal human being. He doesn't represent all trans/fluid people. There's no special etiquette or magic formula of to act around them or how to react when they're coming out of the closet.

**Treat them the way they want to be treated.** It sounds obvious, but you should see how they are about being trans/fluid. Does your friend's family, friends or other relatives know about it, or does your friend want to keep it silent? Are they have difficulty with being trans/fluid, or are they proud of it? If your friend's telling this as a big secret that no-one must know because they're afraid their parents won't accept it, don't treat it as if he just told a random gossip. If your friend says during a conversation, *"oh yeah, I'm trans by the way. Anyway, where was I,"* then sure, you can be surprised, but there's no need to make a big deal out of it, act surprised, worried or anything.

**What you can do now, is to be honest;** tell them that you were surprised and thinking about it for a while *(assuming you are)*. Tell them you're cool with it. Do it in person, texting may come out differently than you mean to.

**TLDR:** No need to hide your surprise. Being acceptable and being normal are different things, so be honest about being surprised. Just keep it clear you're cool with it.